# Python - Writing to CSV file spits all text into one cell

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to take a few text files which have data in the following format :

time_stamp duration word1 p1 word2 p2 ....

and write the data into a CSV file. With each row that I write in, I also want to include the name of the file from which that row is taken.

My problem is that the code I'm executing seems to write all the text into one single cell. When I open the CSV file with LibreOffice, it displays junk characters saying that it cannot display the data correctly because the maximum limit of characters per cell is exceeded.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv, os

path = "./TRIAL with CSV"
all_the_files = os.listdir(path)

for each_file in all_the_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, each_file)
    ifile  = open(file, "rb")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    ofile  = open('CSVtrial.csv', "a")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow([each_file,row])


ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

EDIT : I don't think I can attach a file here, but a sample input file would be a .txt file which has the following lines :

186.860  0.060 (01)      0.89221220 ha(01)       0.04941113 ah(01)       0.04552169 oo(01)       0.01065865 o(01)        0.00219633

187.110  0.410 bongga(01)   1.00000000

187.520  0.349 naman(01)    0.99999601

187.872  0.598 niyan(01)    0.81980968 'yan(02)     0.16510634 iyan(02)     0.00814381 niya(01)     0.00471968 ganyan(01)   0.00139249 diyan(03)    0.00082159

There are some 50,000 such .txt files, which I'm trying to compile into a single CSV file to make it easier to analyse the data.

Here is a screenshot of the kind of error I get when I try to view the CSV file in LibreOffice - https://i.stack.imgur.com/QS0Qa.png

For now I've given up on this and am just trying to work on vim. If anyone has any other suggestions about how I can compile these .txt files into something like a spreadsheet which would make it easier to analyse the data, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Right now you are dumping content from other files in a csv.

Comment: @RickyA, yes that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: @Alvaro, I am able to view the file in vim. I hadn't thought about using different separators. Is there a way I can do that in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the delimiters are correct, this looks wrong:

```
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([each_file,row])
```

because that will create a row with exactly two columns, where the second cell will contain the whole original row, serialized.

Should be rather:

```
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([each_file] + row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made that correction. It looks neater in vim now, but I still see the same problem in LibreOffice. All the data still going into just 1 cell.

Comment: @ubuntunoob Could you share an example input file that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, not related to your question: Are you sure you want a tab delimiter? Maybe a comma delimited would be better for the output.

Second, it looks like your input files are SPACE delimited, and yet you create the reader with the default COMMA delimited. You might want to try to pass in a delimiter:

```
reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=' ')
```

Not sure if that helps, some sample data might be useful so I can muck around with it here.

EDIT: I also noticed that you are trying to concatenate files into a single file? Am I correct in that assumption?

For that, I might use other (i.e. unix) tools that will get that done much faster. If your goal is to just do something fun in python my recommendation might be to declare a single writer outside the loop rather than reopening the same file with append mode.

EDIT2: without knowing much more about your code, I might approach it as follows:

```
writer = csv.writer(open('CSVTrial.csv', 'w'), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for each_file in all_the_files:
    file = os.path.join(path, each_file)
    with open(file, "rb") as ifile:
        reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=" ")
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow([each_file] + row)
ofile.close()
```

notice of course that the with statement in the reader file is meant to avoid the explicit close() on the file. The writer can have an explicit close or you can use the same treatment. It's also nice that the input files are guaranteed to close even if exception happens. You have to make sure the output file closes as well, using some try...catch...finally

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @mlnyc, I tried a few things and I realised my input files are tab delimited. I tried passing in a delimiter in the reader like you said, and changed the delimiter to a comma in the output. None of these combinations makes any difference. I can still see the output fine in vim, but in LibreOffice it still gives me junk characters all in 1 cell.
What kind of sample data should I provide? Text lines from the files?

Comment: I think text lines from the file is a good start.  You can probably print the row as well before you write it out to make sure it was properly parsed. There could be other issues, but without further information I'm not sure how to diagnose them... I did add a complete example if it helps

Comment: @ubuntunoob I would start by listing all the things I assume are true. For example an assumption might be: the input files all open properly, or the reader parses all inputs into a list. Then validate that each assumption is true. Programming is making assumption, debugging is verifying your assumptions :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @mlnyc. I tried them but I'm getting the same problem. Printing out the lines and counting them tells me that the rows are being properly parsed. As someone else mentioned, it could be a problem with the spreadsheet app. I am indeed trying to concatenate files into a single file - can you point me towards tools that woul help me do this in Unix?

Comment: @ubuntunoob ok good. Now, your issue is that the output file opens properly, has proper delimiters of your choosing, but all the text is on a single file? Try to find libreOffice's equivalent to Excel's text to columns functionality. We are using tabs for the delimiter so that is what you will choose. Hope that helps. Try this: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_to_Columns and if they only support commas, you might want to change the writer's delimiter to a comma

Comment: Tried this, didn't help. Still junk characters. I think I'll just have to work on the file from vim. Thanks for all your help @mlnyc!

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with a simple text editor.. probably the problem isn't in your code. Some spreadsheet apps use "," as a separator. Others use ";" or even " " or tab.
If the file looks like what it should, try using a different separator